# HTML5 Audio tag no sound safari Desktop and IOS

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-audio

I'm trying to play a simple HTML5 audio tag on Safari, this is my code:

```
 <audio controls>
    <source src="https://www.tarteel.io/media/56_85_3040853518.wav" type="audio/wav" />
 </audio>
```

I've tried to create an Element with `document.createElement` and injecting it into the document and tried to use `new Audio()` and also tried this pattern:

```
this.audio.play()
this.audio.pause()
```

but no solution the video gives me an error like this [image]

Any help ? This is all my code.

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vvamxQ. Check your browser's error console for details of the error.

Comment: Safari has support since 3.1 according to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility) - are you using older?

Comment: @ceejayoz on Safari? Doesn't work for me neither.

Comment: @ceejayoz bro no logs for me just this

Comment: @forthe I'm using version 12 bro

Comment: @Kaiido where's the duplicate question ? I tried all the solutions of the old questions but didn't work for me, so it's a different case

Comment: @BaHaaJr. you mean you did try to set up a ReadableStream etc.? ;-) Sorry, but I don't bite it. I just tried the solution 2 from my dev tools console and it works (obviously, you need to do it from `https://www.tarteel.io`, or you won't be authorized to fetch the resource at all). And I just re-checked `curl --range 0-99 https://www.tarteel.io/media/56_85_3040853518.wav -o /dev/null` from my terminal and it did download the whole 784KB of the file => The server hosting your file still doesn't accept Range-requests. Still a dupe.

Comment: @Kaiido yeah I noticed that but any recommendations ?? I'm using Django app as the server.

Comment: Thank you for that hint, I'll give this a try: 
https://github.com/wearespindle/django-ranged-fileresponse/